# How to use numeric int in exec sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Is there any way i can use numeric integer in sp_executesql ?

```
declare @total_test int
declare @test int
set @sql=N'select @test=count (*) from '+@db+'..'+@table
exec sp_executesql @sql
set @total_test +=@test
```

The problem is that he will not accept any numeric integet, 
i cant even set @sql=N'select count (*)...'

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you working on all three versions at the same time? Sql Server 2005/2008/2012 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `OUTPUT` clause with your variable. Also on a side note you must use `QUOTENAME()` function when concatenating object names to your dynamic sql string, protects you against possible sql injection attack.

```
declare @total_test int;
declare @test int;
SET @total_test = 0;

set @sql=N'select @test=count (*) from '+ QUOTENAME(@db)+'..'+ QUOTENAME(@table)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
                     ,N'@test int OUTPUT'
                     ,@test OUTPUT
set @total_test +=@test
```

Comment: `@total_test` should probably be initialized somewhere as `NULL += @test IS NULL`

Comment: Not a problem gald it helped :)

Comment: What QUOTENAME() function does is put suqare brackets `[]` around the passed parameter. So whatever is passed to that parameter is treated as an object name. If you have that Server setup as linked server and the syntax works.

Comment: as far as the error message is concered I think you are using a Variable '@table_sum' which you havent declared before you passed it to the dynamic sql. Dont forget any variable you pass to dynamic sql you must declare that variable when passing parameters to system stored procedure sp_executesql because sp_executesql has its own scope and any variable that has been declared out of its scope arnt accessable to sp_executesql.